# Connect to stratum server in NODEJS

Tags: node.js, stratum

I'm trying for several days to connect to a stratum server in nodejs. But I don't get my code working.
I've tried several npm packages but most of them are outdated.
Then I found [node-stratum](https://github.com/pocesar/node-stratum).

This package works fine locally so I expected that it works also with a remote server.
After I changed to host and port to `pool.minexmr.com` with port number `4444`

I got this error message

```
Oops error:  Error: Stratum request without method or result field
at serverForEachCommand (C:\Users\JP\Documents\xmr-web\node_modules\stratum\lib\server.js:350:19)
at arrayEach (C:\Users\JP\Documents\xmr-web\node_modules\stratum\node_modules\lodash\index.js:1289:13)
at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JP\Documents\xmr-web\node_modules\stratum\node_modules\lodash\index.js:3345:13)
at Object.processCommands (C:\Users\JP\Documents\xmr-web\node_modules\stratum\lib\server.js:298:9)
at Object.handleData (C:\Users\JP\Documents\xmr-web\node_modules\stratum\lib\client.js:138:38)
at Socket.twoArgs (C:\Users\JP\Documents\xmr-web\node_modules\better-curry\index.js:74:18)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

I used to code in the example/client
My full code is here [codepile](https://www.codepile.net/pile/dpM89AqG)

I also tried to change the host to miningpoolhub but there I got no error and it stops by the `console.log('Sent!')` so I figured out that I better stick with `pool.minexmr.com`

In the codepile I also added the other logs from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally I got the answer.
Monero stratum has a different payload than Bitcoin
With Wireshark I filtered the payload out en changed the client code van node-stratum.
I changed the node-stratum core code a bit too.